# Refer classes by their metadata tag

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Is it possible to find(probably with the mirror API) all classes(in my project) with some metadata annotation?

Example:

```dart
import 'baz.dart'; //more tagged classes

@Tag(#foo)
class A{

}
@Tag(#foo)
class B{

}

void main() {
 List<ClassMirror> li = getClassMirrorsByTag(#foo);
}
```

Comment: Fixed a bit. Now it's as clear as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer:

**getClassMirrorsByTag.dart**

```dart
library impl;
@MirrorsUsed(metaTargets: Tag)
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Tag {
  final Symbol name;
  const Tag(this.name);
}
List<ClassMirror> getClassMirrorsByTag(Symbol name) {
  List<ClassMirror> res = new List<ClassMirror>();
  MirrorSystem ms = currentMirrorSystem();
  ms.libraries.forEach((u, lm) {
    lm.declarations.forEach((s, dm) {
      dm.metadata.forEach((im) {
        if ((im.reflectee is Tag) && im.reflectee.name == name) {
          res.add(dm);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  return res;
}
```

**extra.dart**

```dart
library extra;
import 'getClassMirrorsByTag.dart';

@Tag(#foo)
class C {}
```

**main.dart**

```dart
library  main;
import 'getClassMirrorsByTag.dart';
import 'extra.dart';
@Tag(#foo)
class A{}
@Tag(#baz)
class B{}


void main() {
  print(getClassMirrorsByTag(#foo));
}
```

**output:**

> [ClassMirror on 'A', ClassMirror on 'C']

Comment: the List<ClassMirror> res = new List<ClassMirror>(); worked fine with classes, but not with functions, do you have an idea if I want to use the same with functions, what shall I use instead of this line, thanks

Comment: @HasanAYousef Function mirrors have  type `MethodMirror` and classes `ClassMirror` If you replace it with `List res = new List();` then you will have mixed type collection of mirrors.

Comment: thanks, can you help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826521/executing-bundle-of-functions-by-their-metadata-tag-in-dart-lang